# How to iterate through a range in a column and paste the non-blank results horizontally using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am currently trying to iterate through a range of cells which determines if the cell is blank or not. If it is blank and/or has a "No" indicator for the Law Debt field, I move onto the next cell, however if there is data populated into that cell and law debt has a "Yes" indicator, I want to be able to grab that value and paste it into another cell however I need it to be pasted horizontally. So based off of the below table, assuming the range ends at "A1:A3", I would want the data to be pasted horizontally like the following:
A4 = $1450.00, B4 = blank, C4 = $325.00 etc. I am only able to get my code to pull the first cell value and not loop through the entire column. Thanks in advance!

| Law Debt (A) | Adj_month_amt (B) | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | $1450.00 | -------- |
| No | $1275.75 | -------- |
| Yes | $325.00 | -------- |

```
Dim cell as Range

For Each cell In ws_loans.Range("N3:N22")
If cell <> "" And Cells(3, 0).offset(0,1) <> "No" Then
    ws_loans.Range("N3").Copy ws_loans.Range("C49").Offset(0, 1)
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use `For loop` is better because you just need to check column `Law Debt (A)`

If value is not equal to `Yes`, then nothing to do and it will skip the cell

```
Dim ws_loans As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim rowcount As Integer
Set ws_loans = Sheets(1) 'Assume your worksheet is sheets(1)
rowcount = ws_loans.Range("A1:A4").Rows.Count 'change range("A1:A4") to your testing area
Dim cell As Range


For i = 0 To rowcount - 1

   With ws_loans
   
      'Change Range("A1") to your first top cell of your testing area
      If .Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = "Yes" Then
          
         'Loop the last row
         For Each cell In .Range(.Range("A1").Offset(rowcount, 0), .Range("A1").Offset(rowcount, rowcount - 1))
             
             'If cell value is empty, paste the value to it and exit for each loop
             If cell.Value = "" Then
             
                .Range("A1").Offset(i, 1).Copy cell
                
                Exit For
                
             End If
             
         Next
         
      End If
      
   End With
   
Next i
```

Comment: So this answer works best so far for what I need, however if the law debt is indicated as a "No" the horizontal paste area also skips to the next cell. Is there a way to safeguard against this so that the paste area only moves onto the next cell if a value is being pasted into it? For example: Law debt is: Yes, Yes, No, Yes and the values are: 1, 2, 3, 4. If the paste area is A4:D4, then the results should be A1=1, B1=2, C1=4. Currently, the code would have the same result as mentioned, however C1 is passed over and D1=4, I need the paste area to only move forward if a value is being inserted.

Comment: @bgado I have edited my answer. You need to use for each loop to loop the last row and paste value to empty cell and break the loop

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly below is my code hope it solves your requirement. I have attached image for my understanding of your data arrangement. Please try this and let me know your feedback. The code is tested on my data. I have added comments which are self explanatory.

[Your data arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP0P7.png)

```
    Option Explicit


Sub CopyHorizontally()

Dim Cpy As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long, oRow As Long, oCol As Long, Lrownew As Long
Dim c As Range, Rng As Range
Dim RetVal As Variant


Set Cpy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CpyHor")

''' last row of your data
Lrow = Cpy.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Cpy.Range("A1").CurrentRegion


'' loop through column A containing Yes and No
For Each c In Cpy.Range("A2:A" & Lrow).Cells

    If c.Value = "Yes" Then
        ''' If Yes then return value is amount from column B
        RetVal = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        
        Else
        
        ''' Else return value is OK which we will later delete and replace with blank
        RetVal = "OK"
    
    End If
    
    Set Rng = Cpy.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set Rng = Rng(Rng.Count)
    Debug.Print Rng.Value
        
        
    ''' Row number and column number of last filled cell
    oRow = Rng.Row
    oCol = Cpy.Range("D" & oRow).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    
  
    ''' Find row and column of next cell
    If oCol = 1 Or oCol = 2 Then
            oCol = oCol + 1
            
        
        ElseIf oCol = 3 Then
            oCol = 1
            oRow = oRow + 1
    End If

''' populate return value in next empty cell
Cells(oRow, oCol).Value = RetVal

Next c

Lrownew = Cpy.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
''' Replace all "OK" cells with blank
For Each c In Cpy.Range("A" & Lrow & ":C" & Lrownew).Cells
    If c.Value = "OK" Then
    
        c.Value = ""
        
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

[Your data arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex79C.png)